# Javascript Axios Delete request ERR failed

Tags: javascript, axios

I've made a method for Deleting by id from my API Spring, when i am doing the request with Postman everything works, but when i am trying to do it with my code i am getting errors. I am using a CORS plugin. GET request works, but delete does not. My code bellow and my errors:
Method DELETE:

```
DELETE(url) {
        try {
            console.log(axios.post(url, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            }));
            return axios.delete(url)
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
  deleteDiscount(id) {
        return new Promise((resolve => {
            this.DELETE(`http://localhost:8080/discount/${id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response.data)
                }).catch();
        }))
    }
```

So, when i am doing it i get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/discount/d1' from origin 'http://localhost:63343' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
DELETE http://localhost:8080/discount/d1 net::ERR_FAILED
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (isAxiosError.js:10)
```

and in console log :

```
_proto__: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
__proto__: Object
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: Error: Network Error at e.exports (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2:9719) at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2:8491)
config: {url: "http://localhost:8080/discount/d1", method: "delete", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
isAxiosError: true
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
response: undefined
toJSON: ƒ ()
message: "Network Error"
stack: "Error: Network Error\n    at e.exports (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2:9719)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2:8491)"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: "I am using a CORS plugin" — It doesn't seem to be working… but you haven't shown us the relevant code for it.

Comment: @Quentin , using a CORS plugin in my chrome browser. It do work with other requests. the problem is not in it.

Comment: Why are you making a POST request and a DELETE request at the same time? Why does the POST request have an `application/json` content-type when you aren't POSTing JSON (or anything else at all).

Comment: "using a CORS plugin in my chrome browser. It do work with other requests. the problem is not in it" — Oh. Those are awful. They tend to not work with preflighted requests. Use a real solution instead.

Comment: @Quentin, i just tried some solutions found to see if they work, but does not. Also if i change in console.log to axios.delete the same i obtain)

Comment: Same cause. Delete requests are always preflighted.

Comment: @iftwMZ, if you see your error message your preflight OPTIONS call seems failing `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`  Check what is wrong with options call.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by opening chrome with disabled security. Code works perfectly.
Edit*
Wrote on SPring api a configuration for CORS allowing from everywhere, works perfectly without plugin or disabling security.